# After insertAdjacentHTML, some elements are partially shown even if scrolling enabled, how to avoid coverage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please run the code snippet to understand my question.

after clicking the square for 2 times, the scrollbar is visible. However the left-/right-most square is partially shown, I don't know how to avoid this.

Also want to emphasize that I:

1. **prefer center-aligning** the squares.
2. **both horizontal and vertial** insertions are to be implemented.

The final desired outcome / sample output is demonstrated by this GIF:

[image: .]

```js
function insertElement(ev) {
  let this_node = ev.target;
  this_node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="square" onclick="insertElement(event);"></div>');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff280;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.square {
  min-width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square" onclick="insertElement(event);"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's because of `justify-content: center;`... what is the desired outcome though?

Comment: Simply change `justify-content` to `flex-start`

Comment: can you please show some sample output?

Comment: @Aprillion I wanted to mimic a Excel-like cell appending behavior. An app called TreeSheets has this feature, but it's not web-based.

Comment: The outcome / sample output is demonstrated in this GIF https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1609306/61577169-43678a00-ab16-11e9-9766-d51b6c393e21.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep centered style without overflow and left alignment after overflow, 2 containers are needed, with the inner one adapting to the width of content (not parent), e.g. using `display: inline-flex`, like this:

```js
function insertElement(ev) {
  let this_node = ev.target;
  this_node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="square" onclick="insertElement(event);"></div>');
}
```

```css
.scrollContainer {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.centerContainer {
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: visible;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff280;
}

.square {
  min-width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scrollContainer">
    <div class="centerContainer">
      <div class="square" onclick="insertElement(event);"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, I will try applying it, and accept the answer afterwards 

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `flex-wrap: wrap` to make sure the boxes break into multiple lines.

```js
function insertElement(ev) {
  let this_node = ev.target;
  this_node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="square" onclick="insertElement(event);"></div>');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff280;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.square {
  min-width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square" onclick="insertElement(event);"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, it's my fault not having mentioned the constraints in advance...

Comment: Scrolling is desired, but wrapping is not. here is the final desired outcome demonstrated in GIF: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1609306/61577169-43678a00-ab16-11e9-9766-d51b6c393e21.gif